# Autoplay in slick slider stop working after on Next or Previous arrows click

Tags: slider, slick.js

I have slick slider on my page. After click on Next or Previous arrows in slick slider autoplay stop working. But when I click on any place on the page it starts to autoplay again. How I can fix this? I need to have autoplay even after arrow click.

JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    if ($slider.length) {
        $slider.slick({
            slidesToShow: 7,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 1500,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: true,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this need to add:

```
pauseOnFocus: false, 
pauseOnHover: false
```